# スライス記法を利用できるメソッドを自作したい。

Tags: python, python3

スライス記法を利用できるメソッドを自作したいです。
クラスを作成し、__getitem__メソッドをオーバーライドすることで、
スライス記法が利用できることが分かりました。
__getitem__以外のメソッドの引数で、スライス記法を利用できるようにするには、
どうしたらよいでしょうか？

my_list[1:2] ←これはできました。
my_list.my_method[1:2] ←これができるようにしたいです。

```
import typing as t


class CustomList():
    def __init__(self, list: t.List[t.Any] = None):
        self.list = list or []

    def get_item(self, index: t.Union[int, slice]) -> t.List[int]:
        # 独自メソッド
        return self.list[index]

    def __getitem__(self, index: t.Union[int, slice]) -> t.List[int]:
        # 組み込み関数を追加
        return self.list[index]


print('◇独自メソッドの呼び出し')
custom_list = CustomList([11, 22, 33, 44])
print(custom_list.get_item(1))
# print(custom_list.get_item(1:2))  # ←SyntaxError: invalid syntaxが発生する。

print('◇インデクサをオバーライドした場合')
print(custom_list[1])
print(custom_list[1:2])
```

以下、実行結果です。

```
◇独自メソッドの呼び出し
22
◇インデクサをオバーライドした場合
22
[22]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メソッドの呼び出しでは `instance.method(arg, ..)` の書式 (丸括弧) になり
その中ではスライスは使えないはずです。

メソッドではなくデータのメンバーであれば(そしてそれが シーケンスオブジェクトであれば)可能

```py
class Cls:
    def __init__(self, list: t.List[t.Any] = None):
        self.list = list or []
    # self.list は publicなメンバーとする

v = Cls([11, 22, 33, 44])
print(v.list[1])
print(v.list[1:2])
```

Answer (score 1):

※ `list` は組み込みクラスなので、変数名を `lst` に変更しています。

```py
import typing as t

class CustomList():
    def __init__(self, lst: t.List[t.Any] = None):
        self.lst = lst or []

    @property
    def get_item(self):
        # 独自メソッド
        return self.lst

    def __getitem__(self, index: t.Union[int, slice]) -> t.List[int]:
        # オーバーライド
        return self.lst[index]


print('◇独自メソッドの呼び出し')
custom_list = CustomList([11, 22, 33, 44])
print(custom_list.get_item[1])
print(custom_list.get_item[1:2])

print('◇インデクサをオバーライドした場合')
print(custom_list[1])
print(custom_list[1:2])

# ◇独自メソッドの呼び出し
# 22
# [22]
# ◇インデクサをオバーライドした場合
# 22
# [22]
```

Answer (score 0):

ありがとうございます。理解できました。
（丸カッコと、鍵カッコをごっちゃにして考えていました。）

my_class[1:2] ←OK
my_class.my_list[1:2] ←OK。my_listに__getitem__メソッドが実装されていればよい。
my_class.my_method(1:2) ←NG。できない。